# How to convert short dates to this format: DDD MMM DD YYYY GMT+0800 (X country standard time)?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, luxon

When I do `new Date()` I get:

```
Thu Dec 28 2017 10:17:58 GMT+0800 (台北標準時間)
```

If I apply `.valueOf()` to that date I  get:

```
1514427724039
```

Which is what I want.

Now, I need to apply `.valueOf()` to a date like this: `2017/12/28`. I tried using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/tour.html) to convert the date (since applying `.valueOf()` to YYYY/MM/DD doesn't produce a number):

```
DateTime.fromISO(startDate.replace(/\//g, '-')).toRFC2822()
// => Thu, 28 Dec 2017 00:00:00 +0800
```

However, applying `valueOf()` that results returns the same string. Not a number like in the first example.

What should I do so I can produce a numeric value from `YYYY/MM/DD`? Just I did with `DDD MMM DD YYYY GMT+0800 (X country standard time)`?

Comment: did you try with `moment.js`? I am pretty sure, it will help you. Link: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: `DateTime.fromISO(startDate.replace(/\//g, '-')).valueOf()` https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-valueOf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're losing track of the types.

`fromISO()` returns Luxon DateTime object, but `toRFC2822` returns an RFC 2822 string representation of the date.

So your `valueOf()` was being called on the string, not the DateTime.

As others have pointed out, you need only call `valueOf()` on the result of `fromISO()`.

To illustrate:

```js
var dt = luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2017-12-05'); // returns a Luxon DateTime object
console.log('fromISO returns an', typeof dt);

var rfc = dt.toRFC2822(); // returns a string
console.log('toRFC2822 returns a', typeof rfc);

var valueOfRFC = rfc.valueOf(); // string.valueOf() is just that string
console.log('strings are their own values?', rfc === valueOfRFC);

var valueOfDT = dt.valueOf(); // this is what you want
console.log('value of datetime', valueOfDT);
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Luxon you can:

- use [`valueOf()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimevalueof) instead of [`toRFC2822()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetorfc2822) (as Slai suggested in the comments)
- use [`fromString`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromstring) removing `replace`

```js
var startDate = '2017/12/28';
var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
// fromISO with regex
console.log( DateTime.fromISO(startDate.replace(/\//g, '-')).valueOf() );
// fromString instead of regex
console.log( DateTime.fromString(startDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd').valueOf() );
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to use momentjs (Luxon's "big brother"), you can simply use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```js
var startDate = '2017/12/28';
console.log( moment(startDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').valueOf() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

By default, both luxon and moment parse string as local time.

---

You can also use vanilla JavaScript, see [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

- `new Date(year, month, day)` (*The argument month is 0-based*)
- `new Date(dateString)` (IS0 8601 compliant format, e.g. 2017-12-28. Unsupported on Firefox <=3 and IE <=8)

```js
var startDate = '2017/12/28';
var arr = startDate.split('/');
console.log( new Date(arr[0], arr[1]-1, arr[2]).valueOf() );
console.log( new Date(startDate.replace(/\//g, '-')).valueOf() );
```

Please note that:

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object will accept a YYYY/MM/DD string as-is. From there, you can use `.getTime()` to get a timestamp:

```
var startDate='2017/12/28'; 
var dateStamp = new Date(startDate); // e.g. "Thu Dec 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)"
var timeStamp = dateStamp.getTime(); // e.g. 1514440800000
```